# MySQL storage and retrieval Logic - free-form dynamic data - user entered values

Tags: mysql, logic

I'm looking for a solution to storing and retrieving user entered data as a drop down list.

---

The user wants to start with an existing drop list containing values of breeds.

**Breed Select List**

```
<select>
<option value="0">select</option>
<option value="1">Afghan Hound</option>
<option value="2">Airedale Terrier</option>
<option value="3">American Bulldog</option>
<option value="4">Belgian Malinois</option>
</select>
```

---

A breed Table exists

```
|breed_id|  breed_title   |
---------------------------
|   1    |  Afghan Hound  |
|   2    |Airedale Terrier|
|   3    |American Bulldog|
|   4    |Belgian Malinois|
```

---

The breed_id value will be saved with the pet values

```
|pet_id| pet_name | pet_sex |breed_id|
--------------------------------------
|  1   | 'Foo Foo'|   'M'   |    2   |
|  2   | 'Sparky' |   'f'   |    4   |
|  3   |  'Spot'  |   'M'   |    1   |
```

---

Because there are so many different types of breeds and because of the potential for entering erroneous breed types - The user wants to be able to add, edit and DELETE breed types.

I can see that I can edit and add breed types in/to the breed table. But what if the user deletes a breed, lets say breed #2:

```
|breed_id|  breed_title   |
---------------------------
|   1    |  Afghan Hound  |
|   3    |American Bulldog|
|   4    |Belgian Malinois|
```

The pets association to that breed is lost:

```
|pet_id| pet_name | pet_sex |breed_id|
--------------------------------------
|  1   | 'Foo Foo'|   'M'   |   (2)  |<<<<<<<
|  2   | 'Sparky' |   'f'   |    4   |
|  3   |  'Spot'  |   'M'   |    1   |
```

---

What do I do about the association between a pet that has a breed_id that has been deleted from the breed table?

The next time the pet is called and I try to populate the **Breed Select List** - breed #2 is gone. What do I do with that pets breed now? How do I populate my drop list now?

---

I can think of a few ways to handle this - but I am not sure of correct solution - or best practice.

I realize that there may be more a, logic or data entry method, type of solution. Whatever the solution is - I just want to know how the pro's handle this sort of thing.

Thank you : )

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to handle dogs which reference deleted breeds would depend on why the breed needed to be changed.

Each different reason will have a different outcome as they are trying to achieve different things. A few are:

1. A breed was mis-spelt or renamed
2. Two breeds are actually one
3. An errant (non existant) breed was created

I would suggest the following behaviour for each case

1. **Rename** simply update the existing breed table, being able to do this is one of the primary motivations of normalising the breed data in the first place.
2. **Merging**, If you decide *'Afghan Hound'*, and *'Kuchi Hound'* are actually the same breed, then you would first change all the dogs which are referencing *'Afghan Hound'* to instead reference *'Kuchi Hound'* then you can delete the 'Afghan Hound' breed without worrying about dangling references.
3. **Delete**, say a breed *'Yo Mama'* was created, if you decide that the dogs which are of this breed type are also not desired, you can first delete all the dogs which reference *'Yo Mama'* then the breed. If you wanted to keep the dogs, I would suggest creating an *'unknown'* breed  type, or making the breed *NULLable*, and set the breed of all the *'Yo Mama'* dogs to NULL before deleting the breed.

Either way, these outcomes will depend on the type of behaviour you want for you specific system, but I hope this gives you an idea of some common types of migrations.